# Char representation of UNICODE character doesn't always return a character

Tags: c#, unicode, char, type-conversion

I have a routine that given an int, returns the equivalent UNICODE character. For some values though, it doesn't retun a character, but its (I presume) Hex value.

For example:

17664 ---> '䔀' // **CORRECT!**

BUT

56384 ---> '\udc40' // **WRONG!!!**

Why is that?

Comment: How about showing us the code of the routine?

Comment: I simply cast the int value as char: return (char) result;

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: private static char getChar(int t)
        {
            return (char) num;
        }

Comment: Sorry, 'num' should be 't'

Comment: Unfortunately though, there seems to be a problem when I try writing it to file. I created a string with all the concatenated UNICODE characters and use File.WriteAllText(dstPth, result); to try and write it to file, but I get an exception telling me that it cannot convert that value. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character with code 0xdc40 is a [*Low Surrogate*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/surrogates-and-supplementary-characters).

That means that it is one half of a 32-bit character (which is represented as a 16-bit low surrogate plus a 16-bit high surrogate UTF16 character), and thus does not correspond to an actual character.

That's why the output is showing `'\udc40'` rather than a single character.

Comment: Great! Thank you for the explanation. I'm trying to write to file a string with all the concatenated UNICODE characters (File.WriteAllText(dstPth, result);), but if I try writing the string containing the above value, I get an exception telling me that it cannot convert that value. How do I write it to file?

Comment: @user2729463 You can't really have one half of a surrogate pair - it would be missing information, so you can't legally write such a half character to a valid unicode file.

Comment: How do I obtain the other half so that I can concatenate it to the string and write the complete pair?

Comment: Well there are multiple possible other halves, so you can't really say.